# Enabling small capitals

Tags: css

On MS Word we have a text feature called "Small Capitals". It turns all letters uppercase, but the lowercase letters turn smaller then uppercased. I need to know if it is possible in CSS.

Example:

**Original**: Hello World
**Small Capitals**: **H**ELLO **W**ORLD

**Notes**: SO Markdown does not support CSS `font-size` style in tags nether `small`, so I show as a hack. Well, the **strong** letters is bigger than normal letter in small capitals.

Is it possible in CSS? How I can do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s called “small capitals” or “small caps” in English. In typography, small capitals are separately designed (by font author) versions of letters. They have the shapes of capital letters, but their height is usually just a litter larger than the x-height (the height of the lowercase letter “x”) of the font. They may be implemented in a small caps font, but more often, they are glyph variants inside font.

In MS Word up to and including Word 2007, as well as in CSS implementations for `font-variant: small-caps`, the “small capitals” are really just reduced-size capital letters. (Word 2010 gives access to OpenType features and real small caps.) This typically means that their stroke widths are too small, and to avoid this effect from getting all too bad, the font size reduction is rather modest, so the fake “small caps” are not that much smaller than normal capitals.

For such reasons, “small caps” are mostly best avoided on web pages.

However, there is ongoing work in giving access to OpenType features in CSS. Currently, support exists in the form of browser-prefixed versions of the [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-feature-settings) property as proposed in *CSS3 Fonts*. Example:

```
<style>
body { 
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
.sc { 
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
  -ms-font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
  font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
}
</style>
<div class=sc>Hello world</div>
<div><span style="font-variant: small-caps">Hello world</span>
  (fake small caps)</div>
```

This works on supporting browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 10), provided that the font has small capitals (e.g., Calibri, Cambria, Candara, Constantia, Corbel, Palatino Linotype).

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do it with `font-variant`. I think you mean "capitalized"

```
<span style="font-variant:small-caps;">Hello World</span>
```

Comment: This is wrong.  `font-variant:small-caps` produces **fake** small-caps.

Comment: @MattMc thanks for repeating the great answer of Jukka from 2012 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110272/enabling-small-capitals/13111159#13111159)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about small caps, So try:

**font-variant: small-caps;**

Answer (score 0):

Usually by "small caps" it's intended a style where all capital letters are preserved as they are and lowercase letters are rendered in uppercase using as a smaller variant of the font.

Using `text-transform: uppercase;` will convert all letters to uppercase, but will not achieve the effect of rendering them with a smaller font.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.php

Using `font-variant: small-caps;` will achieve the result described above, i.e. render all lowercase letters to uppercase using a smaller font size (which, as mentioned by @jukka-k-korpela) is usually done via dedicate glyphs within the font itself.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-variant.php

There's also `font-variant-caps: all-small-caps;` which forces the small-caps effect on all letters (lowercase and uppercase alike). This might be useful in some edge cases, e.g. in older styling conventions where 'A.D.' and 'B.C.' would be rendered with smaller letters, i.e. combining the effects of `text-transform: uppercase;` and `font-variant: small-caps;`.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-variant-caps.php